# omission of a subjective relative pronoun and be verb

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

> The 4-year-olds often chose to look at the marshmallows while waiting, a strategy **that was** not terribly effective.

Can I omit "that was" in the sentence above?

Comment: Yes: you can. The AdjP "not very effective" would then be a post-head modifier of "strategy".

Answer (score 1):

> The 4-year-olds often chose to look at the marshmallows while waiting, a strategy not terribly effective.

That sounds perfectly fine and concise.

From what I understand, usually you drop a relative pronoun when it's followed by a present/past participle, or when it is the *object* in the second clause:

- [It was a strategy.] [*It* was needing some adjustments.] = It was a strategy (*that was*) needing some adjustments.
- [It was a strategy.] [*It* was devised by Tom.] = It was a strategy (*that was*) devised by Tom.
- [It was a strategy.] [She didn't like *it*.] = It was a strategy (*that*) she didn't like.

Those make sense...

But for some reason you can drop it in your example when it's the *subject*, yet not followed by a present/past participle:

- [It was a strategy.] [It was not terribly effective.] = It was a strategy (that was) not terribly effective.

I would **NOT** say "The 4-year-olds often chose to look at the marshmallows while waiting, a strategy not effective." (I would just say "... an ineffective strategy.") So perhaps it's a phrasal thing? I'm honestly not sure. For some reason the "not terribly effective" part sounds a bit British to me.

Answer (score -2):

Absolutely not, the sentence would not make sense without.
If you really want to drop `that was` then try:

`... a not terribly effective strategy.`

Comment: The sentence makes perfect sense without "that was".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  While vaguely intelligible, I cannot see any way to regard it as grammatically correct, and would challenge you to show any native speaker doing so.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  None of those example have the same structure as the OP's post.

Comment: @MikeBrockington The word is spelled **sentence**, not **sentance**.